# XEN 4.1.3 on OpenSuSE 12.2 not seeing keyboard of Dell XPS 1330

Tags: keyboard, virtualization, opensuse, xen

The title really says it all. When booting the XEN Hypervisor kernel, everything works flawlessly, *except* that the keyboard is not seen at all.

If I plug a USB keyboard, it is recognized and I can type normally. The built-in keyboard does not work, and does not even bring the PC out of "lights out" power-saving mode, nor does it react to a REISUB.

I have googled for similar problems on other XEN versions and different hardware, and found that indeed "keyboard not working on laptop" was a documented bug in XEN 4.0.1, having to do with IOAPIC programming. Unfortunately, I am already using a newer version, so the "update to newer XEN" solution wouldn't work (and, indeed, didn't).

I will now investigate APIC/XEN interactions, but I would be grateful if anyone could share some pointers on the matter.

### UPDATE

OK, so it's definitely something having to do with IRQ management. If I add to GRUB parameters

```
acpi=noirq
```

not only does the keyboard get correctly seen, but the strange video refresh lag that I noticed before (and dismissed... I could live with that) disappears.

I'm not posting this as a solution since it was pure voodoo - "*try any boot loader parameter smelling of 8042, ACPI, or IRQ, in random order*". But I'm posting now from the XEN laptop with a VM running, so - at least for now - it *is* working.

An annoying side effect of the "solution" is that, unsurprisingly, interrupt management gets borked. For example, I can type a lengthy `ls -la > dummyfile` command in the Terminal and let it rip, and the command runs... *but prompt does not reappear*. I wait, say, half a minute, and then *move the mouse*; and lo and behold, the prompt reappears, and `dummyfile` has the timestamp of *one minute before*, when the command *did* complete and presumably the prompt *did* reappear, only **the video was not updated**. The same problem manifests itself in the system **apparently** lagging, unless a source of interrupts (the mouse works, the keyboard, network, WiFi and disk drive do not) keeps prodding it.

(This may or may not be related to a "XEN Dom0 interrupt problem" I've been googling).