# OpenSuSE 12.3 kbd service failing at boot

Tags: boot, keyboard, opensuse

An install of OpenSuSE 12.3 (but upgraded from 11.2) displays this message

```
...
Starting Firewall Initialization (phase 2 of 2)                        done
Master Resource Control: runlevel 3 has been                           reached
Failed services in runlevel 3:                                         kbd
Skipped services in runlevel 3:                               irq_balancer

Welcome to openSUSE 12.3 "Dartmouth" - Kernel 2.6.31.14-0.8-desktop (tty1).

brontolo login: _
```

and leaves its keyboard with the default US layout. Since I have an IT keyboard and a password containing international characters, I could no longer log in from console and had to use SSH. Once run `loadkeys` against `tty1` from remote, the console became *loginnable*, but it was pretty awkward.

Anyone had this happen? The keyboard actually *worked* - albeit in US. The only problem (that I could see) was the keymap not being loaded. The `kbd` service has never failed me before (and this is not the same machine with choosy keyboard that got me to ask [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/533143/xen-4-1-3-on-opensuse-12-2-not-seeing-keyboard-of-dell-xps-1330)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason turned out to be a bug in the handling of the `-C` flag of `loadkey`. The `loadkeys` manpage reports (correctly, it turns out)

```
You can specify console device by the -C (or --console ) option
```

But that's *device*, not *devices*. In the `/etc/sysconfig/keyboard` file, the `KBD_TTY` variable holds instead

```
KBD_TTY="tty1 tty2 tty3 tty4 tty5 tty6"
```

and this, in the `/etc/init.d/kbd` file, causes an error:

```
Couldn't open tty tty2 tty3 ...
```

So the solution was to modify the `/etc/init.d/kbd` file,

```
--- loadkeys -C "$KBD_TTY" ...

+++ for tty in $KBD_TTY; do
+++     loadkeys -C $tty ...
+++ done
```

(this kind of code appears in four places in all).

This difference in `loadkeys` was apparently noticed in [another distro](http://lists.crux.nu/pipermail/crux-devel/2011-October/004004.html) (?) in 2011.

Searching in Novell's OpenSuSE BugZilla database searching for "loadkeys" yielded no results, so I just entered it as [bug 813902](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=813902). I reasoned that even if the bug doesn't surface in a normal installation, those lines invoking `loadkeys` are still wrong. And that even if it's because I have the wrong `loadkeys` or `kbd` due to a uncommon installation/upgrade path, that's still a symptom of a bug in the update script.